# In groovy, how do you dynamically call a static method of a class?

Tags: groovy

In groovy, how do you dynamically call a static method of a class?

```
void callMethod(Class c, String staticmethodname){
     //what goes here to call the static method of class c?
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Voila

```
void callMethod(Class c, String staticmethodname){
     c."$staticmethodname"()
}

class test {
  static someMethod() {
    println "me"
  }
}

callMethod(test, "someMethod")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly do it the java-way:

```
c.getMethod(staticmethodname).invoke(null);
```

Comment: The correct version would be: c.getMethod(staticmethodname).invoke(null);

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
def callMethod(Class c, String staticmethodname, args = null ) {
  args ? c."$staticmethodname"( args ) : c."$staticmethodname"()
}

println callMethod( String.class, 'valueOf', 1 )
println callMethod( Calendar.class, 'getInstance' )
```