# How do I dynamically invoke static methods (given as MetaMethod objects) in Groovy

Tags: groovy

As an example, let's take one of StringUtils' methods:

```
def isEmptyMethod = StringUtils.metaClass.getMetaMethod("isEmpty", String)
```

Once I have this method, I can invoke it like this:

```
isEmptyMethod.invoke(null, 'some string')
```

Is this the proper way to invoke static metamethods? The null argument doesn't seem right, but I can't find a "cleaner" way to do this.

EDIT: I see this as one of the answers for the question cfrick likned, but I'm still not convinced about the 'null' parameter...

Comment: possible duplicate of [In groovy, how do you dynamically call a static method of a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474649/in-groovy-how-do-you-dynamically-call-a-static-method-of-a-class)

Comment: `MetaMethod.invoke(Object object, Object[] arguments)` needs the object/delegate/"this".  So if there is none, pass `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Short way:

```
StringUtils."isEmpty"('some string')
```

`MetaMethod` way:

```
def isEmptyMethod = StringUtils.metaClass.getMetaMethod("isEmpty", String)
isEmpty.invoke(null, '')
```